# Django orm query to multiple tables subquery

Tags: python, django-models, subquery, django-orm

I am trying to write a "complex" subquery using django orm.

I have the below tables.

Employer table
employer_id
employer_name

---

Department Table

department_id

employer_id

---

Employee Table

employee_name

department_id

---

My query should return the names of all employees (employee_name) who work for employer with employer_name = "Google".

I have the below sql query and it works just fine:

```
  select * from Employee_Table where department_id in (
     select department_id from Department_Table where employer_id in (
       select employer_id FROM Employer_Table WHERE employer_name="GOOGLE" ) )
```

I am new to Django orm queries and would appreciate some help in understanding how this works in django orm.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm no SQL expert, but I can't imagine it's a good idea to use nested queries when a simple `JOIN` would suffice. As for the question itself, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) (I'm assuming your models contain the relevant Foreign Keys - you don't share those so...)

Comment: Yes. I agree. A join would be best. But I was just trying to understand how a subquery would work for orm and the nested queries felt like a better way to show the flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like this:

```
employers = Employer.objects.filter(name='GOOGLE')
employees = Employee.objects.filter(department__employer__in=employers)
```

I believe that'll generate a subquery, but probably not the one you have written.

What Robin suggested would be this:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(department__employer__name='GOOGLE')
```

Which is likely to be more efficient at the db level.